# Syntax error, Unexpected End of File in simple Laravel application

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to visit /products in my laravel application and I'm getting the following error:

> FatalErrorException in
>   /home2/switchli/public_html/switchgrow.com/laravel/storage/framework/views/8b209faa68f2ec72a2fecf832efc4c82
>   line 14: syntax error, unexpected end of file

The file (8b209faa68f2ec72a2fecf832efc4c82) contains

```
<?php $__env->startSection('title', 'Products'); ?>


<?php $__env->startSection('content'); ?>


    <?php foreach($products as $product): ?>
    {
        <h1><?php echo e($product->id); ?></h1>
    }


<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>
<?php echo $__env->make('layouts.master', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>
```

My controller (ProductController) contains

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

Use App\Product;

class ProductController extends Controller {

    public function index(){
        $products = Product::all();

        return view('products',['products' => $products]);
    }
}
```

My products.blade.php view contains

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Products')


@section('content')


    @foreach ($products as $product)
    {
        <h1>{{$product->id}}</h1>
    }


@endsection
```

My layouts/master.blade.php contains

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta lang="en" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="description" content="Shop Canadian LED Grow Lights for Commercial Marijuana Growing Projects" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index" />

        <title>Switch GROW - @yield('title')</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/logo.png" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic&amp;subset=latin" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap-material-design-font/css/material.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/web/assets/mobirise-icons/mobirise-icons.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/et-line-font-plugin/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/tether/tether.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/dropdown/css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/animate.css/animate.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/theme/css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/mobirise-gallery/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/mobirise/css/mbr-additional.css" type="text/css" />


</head>

<body>
    <div id="menu-0" custom-code="true">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-dropdown 
            <?php
                /*if (strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 'index.php') !== false) {
                  echo 'transparent';
                }*/
            ?>
            navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="">
                    <div class="mbr-table navbar-table">
                        <div class="mbr-table-cell navbar-cell navbar-header">


                            <a class="navbar-caption" href="index.php" aria-label="Home">
                                <!--<span style="font-weight:normal">switch</span><span style="letter-spacing:-1px">GROW</span>-->
                                <img src="assets/images/switch_grow_logo.svg" alt="Switch GROW Logo" class="switch_grow_logo" style="padding-left:8px" />
                            </a>

                        </div>
                                         <div class="mbr-table-cell navbar-cell">

                                            <button class="navbar-toggler pull-xs-right hidden-md-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar">
                                                <div class="hamburger-icon"></div>
                                            </button>

                                            <ul class="nav-dropdown collapse pull-xs-right nav navbar-nav navbar-toggleable-sm" id="exCollapsingNavbar">
                                                <li class="nav-item">
                                                    <a class="nav-link link mbr-editable-menu-item" href="index.html#header3-k">PRODUCTS</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="nav-item">
                                                    <a class="nav-link link mbr-editable-menu-item" href="#">TECHNOLOGY</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                                    <a class="nav-link link dropdown-toggle mbr-editable-menu-item" href="index.html#pricing-table2-f" data-toggle="dropdown-submenu" aria-expanded="true">RESOURCES</a>
                                                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                                        <a class="dropdown-item mbr-editable-menu-item" href="residential.php">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Residential Cannabis Growing</a>
                                                        <a class="dropdown-item mbr-editable-menu-item" href="commercial_growing.php">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Commercial Cannabis Growing</a>
                                                        <a class="dropdown-item mbr-editable-menu-item" href="food_growing.php">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Food Growing</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="nav-item">
                                                    <a class="nav-link link mbr-editable-menu-item" href="#">CONTACT</a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>

                                            <button hidden="" class="navbar-toggler navbar-close" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar">
                                                <div class="close-icon"></div>
                                            </button>
                                            <a hidden="" class="navbar-caption navbar-close mobile-menu-logo" href="index.php" aria-label="Home" style="left:80px">
                                                <!--<span style="font-weight:normal">switch</span><span style="letter-spacing:-1px">GROW</span>-->
                                                <img src="assets/images/switch_grow_logo.svg" alt="Switch GROW Logo" class="switch_grow_logo" style="padding-left:8px" />
                                            </a>

                                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
    </div>



@yield('content')





<script src="assets/web/assets/jquery/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="assets/tether/tether.min.js">
</script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<script src="assets/smooth-scroll/smooth-scroll.js">
</script>
<script src="assets/dropdown/js/script.min.js">
</script>
<script src="assets/touch-swipe/jquery.touch-swipe.min.js">
</script>
<script src="assets/viewport-checker/jquery.viewportchecker.js">
</script>
<script src="assets/jarallax/jarallax.js">
</script>
<script src="assets/mobirise-gallery/script.js">
</script>
<script src="assets/mobirise-gallery/player.min.js">
</script>
<script src="assets/theme/js/script.js">
</script>






    <input name="animation" type="hidden" />


</body>

</html>
```

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
    <h1>{{ $product->id }}</h1>
@endforeach
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#loops

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much